# How to return queue is empty error?

Tags: java

How do I throw an error in if the queue is empty?

```
public T dequeue() {
        T o = null;
        if (head != null) {
            o = head.getData();
            head = head.getNext();
            queueSize--;
        }
        return o;
```

Comment: `else { throw new SomeException("...");}` But seriously, if you looked this up before coming here, you'd already know this, no?

Answer (score 0):

If a [queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type)) is empty, there is no head node. So create an else clause opposite your check for the head being null.

```
 public T dequeue() {
    T o = null;
    if (head != null) {
        o = head.getData();
        head = head.getNext();
        queueSize--;
    }
    // Otherwise, the head is null
    else{
       // Throw exception
       throw new NoSuchElementException()
    }
    return o;
```

Answer (score 0):

`throw new NoSuchElementException()` if `head == null`.